# Android Back/Menu Key issue

Tags: android, actionscript-3, softkeys

I want to prevent default function of back and menu key and bring up an exit menu at the bottom.. My problem is, when I have a text input function in my app everytime a key is pressed in general brings up the exit menu i created at the bottom and then closes the menu over and over again..

Sorry If I'm being too vague.. here's my code..

"options_mc" is my exit menu I've created.

```
options_mc.visible = false;

function fl_ExitApplication(event:MouseEvent):void
{
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit(0);
}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_OptionsMenuHandler);

function fl_OptionsMenuHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
if((event.keyCode == 95) || (event.keyCode == Keyboard.MENU, Keyboard.DOWN))

{switch (event.keyCode)
{case Keyboard.BACK:
 event.preventDefault();
 trace("back");}
}

{
    if(options_mc.visible == false){
        options_mc.visible = true;
        options_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ExitApplication);
    } else if(options_mc.visible == true){
        options_mc.visible = false;
        options_mc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ExitApplication);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Override the onBackPressed() method in activity

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {

     super.onBackPressed();
     finish();
 }
```

It will stop the activity, ANother way is implementing action menus, see this example

[Link1](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/09/how-to-create-android-menus/)

Comment: Well it's definitely an issue with my back button but i cant figure out where to put that code..